# Any one suggest for sharepoint office365 to have a single list form for all lists in the sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I want to have one List form or Page.
I want to select the List name from the dropdown in the page and accordingly the relevant List fields to be loaded in the page.
If i submit the form data should be saved to the relevant list selected in the Dropdown.

Can anyone suggest the best solution to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For out of box solution, there will be no proper feature fitting your requirements. If you go to site contents page you will see all the lists available, however it seems you want a better experience. I will suggest you to consider creating custom solution with SPFx.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thank you for the response .If we compare PowerApps and SPFX ,which is the best solution to develop?  And also could you provide the few steps or any sample code for spfx solution(similar requirement)to achieve my requirement.